# Android button background image size

Tags: android, android-button

I created a personal keyboard and set the background image to the one of the buttons, but after that button size (with my background) is different from one another.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonShift"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Set background:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonShift"
    android:background="@drawable/sym_keyboard_shift_off"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Please, see the screen of the buttons

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Image size: 106x68

Comment: use image button and set background as image scr background

Comment: For this particular functionality use `ImageButton` instead of `Button` and add this attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

Comment: satnam singh, i'm tried and this doesn't help
http://s45.radikal.ru/i109/1405/dc/f71ba161b03e.png

Comment: @HamidShatu,

 <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonShift"
                    android:background="@drawable/sym_keyboard_shift_off"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:paddingTop="0dip"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

result: http://s020.radikal.ru/i717/1405/cd/cb86a543e01b.png

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to:

1. Change your drawable a bit - remove the orange rectangle background, keep only the arrow with transparent background (from now on I will use the name ***shift_off_arrow*** as a name of described drawable). The transparent background should be only as big as it is needed to keep the whole arrow. Not bigger.
2. Define a new color - the color of your orange background (from this moment I will assume you have defined it and I will be using name ***orange_background***)
3. Use ImageButton instead of Button (just like satnam singh and Hamid Shatu said in a comments to your question)
4. Use code like this (manipulate with all paddings to get the size of the arrow exactly like you want):

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonShift"
    android:background="@color/orange_background"
    android:src="@drawable/shift_off_arrow"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer did not help. I solved this problem with the following code
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonShift"
                    android:background="@drawable/sym_shift_off"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
 />